# How do I count the number of binary matrices with fixed row and column weights?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Given $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, and $b\geq a$ such that $b/a\in\mathbb{N}$, I want to count the number of binary matrices $\mathbf{A}\in\{0,1\}^{a,b}$, where $a$ is the number of rows and $b$ is the number of columns, such that each column of $\mathbf{A}$ contains exactly one element 1 (i.e., weight of one), and each row of $\mathbf{A}$ contains exactly $b/a$ elements 0 (i.e., weight of $b/a$). I am looking for a closed-form formula for the number of such matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to partition the set of $b$ columns into $a$ parts of size $b/a$ each.  The count is the multinomial coefficient $$\binom{b}{b/a,\dots,b/a}=\frac{b!}{(b/a)!^a}.$$